# Sharing different axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to share different axis between two plots in matplotlib? For example in addition to sharing the x axis I would like to share the second axis of the two-dimensional plot with the third axis of the 3d plot:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311, projection='3d')
ax1.scatter(x, y, z)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312,sharex=ax1)
ax2.scatter(x,z)

plt.show()
```

This means, that I want to share the y-axis of one plot with the z-axis of a second plot. Any idea? Thanks a lot!